# Is it possible to have an OptimizePress 2 page which uses the full width?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have set the row to be full width but this only allows background to be full width... I want the content to be full width as well.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: You are on an "I have a coding problem" forum. This question is not related to code you created and have trouble with getting it to work. Your question is software package related. You should try the support of the developer of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible at the moment. But it is something that we are working on.

And you should really try to get help on the official [OptimizePress support page](https://optimizepress.zendesk.com).